# Level up to match my power of eight

Tags: riddle, video-games

> I eat my way around, to avoid get eaten.
>   My prey eats me if I don't eat it first.
>   I have been around from the golden age.
>   Some try to finish me, some claim to finish me.
>   But everyone fails in front of my power of eight.

What am I referring to?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you:

> PAC-MAN?

I eat my way around, to avoid get eaten.

> PAC-MAN eats pellets to score points whilst avoiding ghosts.

My pray eats me if I don't eat it first.

> PAC-MAN has the ability to eat the ghosts if he gets a special pellet.

I have been around from the golden age.

> PAC-MAN is a classic arcade game from "the golden age" of gaming.

Some try to finish me, some claim to finish me.

> PAC-MAN keeps on getting harder and harder the more levels you clear, some people claim that there is an end.

But everyone fails in front of my power of eight.

> Thanks to @Gareth in comments: This refers to the [256th level](https://pacman.fandom.com/wiki/Map_256_Glitch) (2^8) which glitches out and fails due to only using 8-bit integer storage.

Comment: Half way through, but not exactly to what I am referring

Comment: Sorry but I am referring to something specific, also the last line and the title are important

Comment: [This](https://pacman.fandom.com/wiki/Map_256_Glitch), I assume.

Comment: @Gareth McCaughan please state it as an answer so that I can accept it

Comment: Have added Gareth's comment into my answer, giving him credit

Comment: (Yup, definitely better for it to be an edit to AHK's answer than a new one. AHK did all the actual work and I contributed only a small detail.)